# How can I make pinned UV vertices more visible?

Tags: interface, uv-image-editor

I was sent a mesh with the task of unwrapping it. The mesh came with a mangled looking UV map (attached below), but that didn't matter to me- the author wanted /me/ to unwrap this so my task was simply to mark seams and pack the UVs nicely.

After marking some reasonable seams and unwrapping... the UV map was still mangled. It took me quite some time to figure out why. The author had somehow pinned some UV vertices and they were not visible at all when I was looking in the UV editor. A mix of color blindness and visual noise in the map made it very difficult to detect what was happening.

To prevent this from happening in the future and wasting more hours of my time, I'd like to configure blender to show these as larger and brighter vertices. Red doesn't show up very well for me, especially when nested near yellows and greens. Turning off the stretch overlay helps a little, but that isn't an ideal solution for my workflow.

Are there any settings that I can use to adjust the visuals of pinned vertices in the UV editor?

[image: The UV map with pinned vertices that threw me off for hours]

Comment: Not that I know... in the _Preferences_ under _Themes_ > _UV/Image Editor_ you can only change the vertex size - but this affects pinned and unpinned vertices.

You can set a _Vertex_ color, a _Vertex Select_ color and also an _Active Vertex_ color (which doesn't seem to do anything)... but there is no entry for pinned vertices, so I don't know where else this could be set if at all.

Comment: You can change the vertex size in Edit > Preferences > Themes > UV/Image Editor, expand it scroll down and increase Vertex Size. Unfortunately it increases all vetrex sizes so a dense UV map wont look good in edit mode.  I don't see an option to change the pinned vertex color at this time. You can try controlling the display in the Overlays menus (setting UV Opacity temporarily to 0 will make the pinned vertices stand out)

Comment: Unfortunate :/ Would there be a way to do this through the python api? Another option I'm exploring is potentially changing the colors used for the stretch visualization.